# Puppeteer - checkbox.checked is undefined - why?

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer and jest to test some stuff on the front end, and I'm having a small issue - I think there is some concept I'm missing.

```
test("Assert that when checkbox isn't checked, dropdown menu is visible", async () => {
    let checkbox = await page.$('input[ng-model="user.managed.timezone"]');
    console.log("Checking if checkbox checked");
    console.log("CHECKED: ", checkbox.checked);
  });
```

According to the puppeteer docs, page.$ runs document.querySelector. When I run the following on the browser, I get what I want:

`let m = document.querySelector('input[ng-model="user.managed.timezone"]')
console.log(m.checked) // results in true or false`

but the code in jest results in CHECKED: undefined

Why is this the case --> what concept am I missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are trying to read a value of [ElementHandle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-jshandle), it is not the same as pure [JS Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

You have to use this syntax to get `checked` value:

```js
await (await checkbox.getProperty('checked')).jsonValue()
```

Here is working example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
    <html>
        <body>
            <input ng-model="user.managed.timezone" type="checkbox" />
        </body>
    </html>`;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

    const checkbox = await page.$('input[ng-model="user.managed.timezone"]');

    console.log(await (await checkbox.getProperty('checked')).jsonValue());
    await checkbox.click();
    console.log(await (await checkbox.getProperty('checked')).jsonValue());

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: The click() should be inside evaluate() >>> `await page.evaluate((cb) => cb.click(), checkbox)`